# Devise Registration Controller - Split full name and populate first and last name attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise for my authentication.  I have a form for signup that accesses `first_name` and `last_name` as part of the action that Devise uses to create a resource, which is a User in this case.  First_name and last_name are attributes of my User model.

```
<% simple_form_for resource ... %>  

<%= f.input :first_name, label: false, placeholder: "Family Member's First Name", input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40, value: nil } %>

<%= f.input :last_name, label: false, placeholder: "Family Member's Last", input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40, value: nil } %>

<%= ...more fields %>

< % end %>
```

This works fine, but I want to alter the form.  I would like to submit `:full_name` as a single input field in place of the two :first_name and :last_name input fields that I currently have in the form.  Once I submit this form I'd like to:

1. Use this `:full_name` attribute (which is not stored in the model) instead of `:first_name` and `:last_name` as part of the submitted parameters

   ```
   <%= f.input :full_name, label: false, placeholder: "Family Member's Name", input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40, value: nil } %>
   ```
2. Split(or parse in some way) the `full_name` parameter to `first_name` and `last_name` (feel free to leave this method empty if you wish, just place it in the correct location)
3. Save the resource with `:first_name` as `first_name` and `:last_name` as `last _name`.
   (This is my main concern)

I've seen other answer explain how to parse the name or use attributes in Devise not in the model, but I can't find how to save variables as part of the resource that are created after the form is submitted.

Comment: I imagine your biggest problem here will be splitting a "full name" string into "first name" and "last name" correctly. Not everyone has a "full name" consisting of two strings of characters separated by a single space. For that reason I'd recommend against it unless you have a particularly good reason.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but there are plenty of examples out there that are not foolproof but capture a lot of the exceptions. I'm more looking for an answer on how this can be achieved with Devise rather than the parsing method. If you know how to do this feel free to leave the parsing method in pseudo code.

Comment: This might be a problem if for example the user inputted "Maria Joan Santos" wherein the first name should be "Maria Joan" and surname as "Santos" but if your are going to split it or parse it, this might result to "Maria" as first name and "Joan Santos" as surname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. [Virtual Attribute](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes?view=asciicast)**

You'll be able to create a virtual attribute using the [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) method in your model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :full_name
end
```

You'll still need to [sanitize this attr](https://gorails.com/blog/rails-4-0-and-devise-with-strong-params-and-custom-fields) (it just doesn't get saved), which you're doing anyway.

-

**2. Use a [`before_validation` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) in the `User` model**

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :full_name
   before_validation :set_names

   private

   def set_names
      names = full_name.split
      self.first_name = names.first
      self.last_name = names.last
   end
end
```

This will take the submitted *virtual* attribute of `full_name`, split it into an array, and then populate the `first_name` and `last_name` attributes with the results.

The above method will *only* work well with two names. Sorting out other names is another question.

-

**3. See #2**

---

You have to remember `Devise` has no bearing on your `User` model, apart from providing controller support.

The actual `User` data (over the `devise` params) is entirely up to you - we even use a `Profile` model which bolts onto the `User`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
   before_create :build_profile
end 

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich -- Here's another article that was helpful when it came to sanitizing Devise parameters -- http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try virtual attributes? There is an awesome railscast on exactly what you want to do http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes?view=asciicast